# How to attach a created file to mail mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As each user runs through my application I hold their data and dump it into a report as follows, which at the end is created into a pdf document and is later automatically downloaded on the users side(client-side). I now want to attach this document to an email and have it forwarded to them. This is where I have troubles with the attachment.

Code as follows:

```
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/PP_RentalAgreement.rpt")));
            rd.SetParameterValue("rent_agree_no", _1);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_initial", _2);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_f_name", _3);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_l_name", _4);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_id_no", _5);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_lic_no", _6);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_tel", _7);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_cell", _8);
            rd.SetParameterValue("r_fax", _9);

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Stream st = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            st.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var m_message = new MailMessage();
                m_message.To.Add(new MailAddress("JoeSoap@TextMail.com"));
                m_message.Subject = "Pink Panther - Invoice";
                m_message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(st, "application/pdf", "Invoice.pdf"));

                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(m_message);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
```

I am getting an error on this line : `m_message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(st, "application/pdf", "Invoice.pdf"));` saying `The specified content type is invalid.`

Someone suggested to me that I should specify a path however I am not actually saving this file anywhere

How am I able to allow the file to be attached and send it to the recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`System.Net.Mail.Attachment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_) class constructor with 3 overloads consist of these parameters:

```
public Attachment(System.IO.Stream contentStream, string name, string mediaType)
```

Hence, you're assigning name and content type in reversed order, which causing invalid content type problem at this code:

```
m_message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(st, "application/pdf", "Invoice.pdf"));
```

The correct way is putting the file name as second argument like example below:

```
m_message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(st, "Invoice.pdf", "application/pdf"));
```

Or using [`MediaTypeNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames?view=netframework-4.7.2) for content type setting:

```
m_message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(st, "Invoice.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));
```